# Interface does not contain a definition for method

Tags: c#, interface

I have the following two interfaces:

```
public interface IMembershipProvider
{
    object Login(ILoginProviderParameters loginParameters);
    void SetAuthCookie(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie);
}

public interface IFacebookMembershipProvider : IMembershipProvider{}
```

and an implimentation:

```
public class FacebookMembershipProvider: IFacebookMembershipProvider
{
    public object Login(ILoginProviderParameters loginParameters)
    {
        // Facebook login code is here
    }

    public void SetAuthCookie(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
    }
}
```

This is being injected into my controller and assigned to:

```
private readonly IFacebookMembershipProvider _facebookMembershipProvider;
```

I'm able to call the `Login` method without any issue however when I call the `SetAuthCookie` method:

```
_facebookMembershipProvider.SetAuthCookie(user.id, false);
```

I receive the error:

> MyNamespace.UserManagement.Interfaces.IFacebookMembershipProvider'
>   does not contain a definition for 'SetAuthCookie'

What am I doing differently with the Login method that I'm not doing with the SetAuthCookie method?

Explicitly casting to the type `IMembershipProvier` works just fine:

```
((IMembershipProvider)_facebookMembershipProvider).SetAuthCookie(user.id, false);
```

I've probably just missed something rudimentary. Thanks for taking a look.

**UPDATE**

In response to Marks question, the first parameter being passed to the `SetAuthCookie` method comes from a `dynamic` object.

```
dynamic user = _authorizeUserCommand.Invoke(_authorizeUserParams);
```

Comment: +1 It is hard to believe. No old DLLs knocking around your machine? Could it be Resharper/similar old cache?

Comment: I'm having the same issue locally and on my external server. I've removed and re-added the reference to my UserManagement DLL. It seems like it could be a cache issue though.

Comment: Are you using anything like `dynamic`, or any decorator platforms, or anything like that? any meta-programming or IoC/DI stacks? Basically, it looks like some code (typically meta-programming, via ILGenerator) is trying to call the method incorrectly. It doesn't *sound* like something the C# compiler would get wrong.

Comment: Where is the `IFacebookMembershipProvider` interface?

Comment: One of the parameters being passed to the SetAuthCookie method comes from a dynamic object.

`dynamic user = _authorizeUserCommand.Invoke(_authorizeUserParams);`

Comment: and I use Castle Windsor for IoC/DI

Comment: @Jamie k; that could *also* potentially be related, but try the `dynamic` thing first...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The curse of `dynamic` (comments)! Dynamic bleeds. In particular, as soon as you involve `dynamic` in an expression, the **entire thing** is performed with `dynamic` rules, which introduces subtle changes into a number of points.

My advice: resolve the value first:

```
string id = user.id; // this has an implicit cast to string
_facebookMembershipProvider.SetAuthCookie(id, false);
```

which should work fine. You could also use:

```
_facebookMembershipProvider.SetAuthCookie((string)user.id, false);
```

since the explicit cast should end the `dynamic` part of the expression at the argument, so the invoke is **not** `dynamic`.

Comment: @JamieDixon so was user Id a `dynamic` object?

Comment: Yeah. I added it into the comments when Mark asked and I'll include it in the question to make it clearer for future readers.

Comment: @Jamie I'm glad we could find a quick fix, but: I can't decide if this is a bug in the c# dynamic binder or not; have added here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837472/should-an-interface-based-method-invoke-that-uses-dynamic-still-obey-c-sharp-m

Comment: Nice one. I'll keep a track of that question to see what comes up.