# Resolving type with Microsoft Unity and inherited interfaces

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have this classes and interfaces

```
public interface IA{
  void Load();
}

public interface IB : IA{
}

public class B : IB{
   public void Load(){
      //some code
   }
}
```

and I register the `IB` for type `B`

`Microsoft Unity` resolves `IB` to correct type which is `B`, but when I try to call Load it shows an error `IB does not contain a definition for 'Load'`

### Update

This is my unity configuration

```
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

unityContainer.RegisterType<IB, B>();

var obj = unityContainer.Resolve<IB>();
obj.Load()
```

Comment: I would say that that is probably because your class `B` doesn't implement `Load()`

Comment: That's not a unity issue, and  your code above won't even compile. You're doing something else weird.  What are you actually doing?

Comment: @KevinWells I have implemented the Load method in my class, see edited question

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZL8U1N

Comment: It seems that as Will says, you are still leaving out some details. I appreciate the attempt to cut out the unnecessary code for the sake of brevity, but I am guessing that you are cutting out something important that we can't see from the minimal code you are including

Comment: Have you looked at the other questions on SO that pertain to this error message? Such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837002/interface-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-method)?

Comment: @Will I am using Unity to resolve type, in your fiddle there is no `microsoft unity`

Comment: @KevinWells Yes, they are not related to `Unity`

Comment: Please post how your registering IB and how your retrieving an instance of it.

Comment: @RezaRahmati How certain are you that your issue is related to `Unity`? If you aren't sure, then maybe you should check on the things that fixed it for the other question, and see if that is the actual underlying problem

Comment: @mxmissile See the updated question

Comment: Something is still not right, I just copy/pasted all your code and it ran as expected, no Exception. I'm using Unity v4.0 and .NET 4.6.1

Comment: @mxmissile I ma using Unity2.1.505 and .Net4.5.2

Answer (score 1):

IB does not contain definition for Load() but IA does, so you either have to resolve IA to B via unity or once you resolve IB, cast it to IA.

Update 1: I have to agree with other folks here, that the OP code does work and resolve correctly with Unity (tested with .NET 4.5.2 and Unity 2.1.505.2). I am not sure why my suggestion above solved the OP issue, so there has to be some details omitted in the original question.

Update 2: Working Fiddle based on @will's https://dotnetfiddle.net/FoYQSM

Comment: So `Unity` does not honor IB inheriting IA?

Comment: This solves the problem, but I am wondering how the unity doesnot honor the inheritance in Interfaces

Comment: Are the interfaces in the same assembly and do you do any dynamic registration for your container?

Comment: ffs, unity just instantiates types for you. It cannot "respect" or not "respect" the implementation of a type. Yall need help.

Comment: @Will There is a *Your Answer* text box below... use it!

Comment: @mxmissile make me!  Yeah, uh huh, that's what I thought. *gloating luxuriously*